# Use of CPUQuota in systemd

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, systemd

I am trying to put a hard limit in CPU usage for a dd command . I have created the following unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Virtual Distributed Ethernet

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ddcommand
CPUQuota=10%

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

which call the following simple script

```
#!/bin/sh
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024k
```

As I have seen [in this guide](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html), the CPU usage for my `dd` service should not exceed the 10%. But when I run the `system-cgtop` command the usage is about 70-75% .

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

When I execute `systemctl show dd` I get the following results regarding CPU

```
CPUShares=18446744073709551615
StartupCPUShares=18446744073709551615
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=100ms
LimitCPU=18446744073709551615
```

Comment: If you want to create BACKUP with `dd` please forget it,`dd` is low level disk dump, and if you want to recover your backup you will have some problem , please wriet the script for creating tarball and cp via ssh...

Comment: You forgot to mention your Linux distribution and systemd version.

Comment: @MichaelHampton   Hello I am using Fedora 20 64-bit

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I just want to test how I can limit the cpu-usage. So I use the dd command because it uses up to 100% of the CPU and I wan to limit it at 10%

Comment: I am encountering the same problem on Fedora 23 and systemd version 222. The CPUQuota does not seem to have an effect. The service I want to throttle is run as a regular user. Maybe that's relevant...

Comment: @SteveGr2015, what version of systemd is this with?

Comment: @TollefFogHeen it's been a long time since I faced this problem, I overcome it finally by using CPUshares option. Unfortunately I do not remember the systemd version which I used.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## The Good

Your solution is the correct and should actually be quite future-proof; by using systemd to control the services cgroup settings, eg. CPUQota.

```
[Unit]
Description=Virtual Distributed Ethernet

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ddcommand
CPUQuota=10%

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

See the `man systemd.resource-control` for more useful cgroup settings in systemd.

## The Bad

There are two caveats to this though, which I (*and possibly a few others*) stumpled upon. Those caveats are **really** difficult to track down as there does not seem to be much easily findable information about this, which is the main reason for this answer.

### Caveat 1:

The `CPUQuota` setting is only available since systemd 213, see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS

```
    * The CFS CPU quota cgroup attribute is now exposed for
      services. The new CPUQuota= switch has been added for this
      which takes a percentage value. Setting this will have the
      result that a service may never get more CPU time than the
      specified percentage, even if the machine is otherwise idle.
```

This is for example an issue with **Debian Jessie** which only comes with systemd 208. As an alternative one could configure `cpu.cfs_period_us` and `cpu.cfs_quota_us` manually using `cgcreate` and `cgset` from the *cgroup-bin* package, eg.

```
sudo cgcreate -g cpu:/cpulimited
sudo cgset -r cpu.cfs_period_us=50000 cpulimited
sudo cgset -r cpu.cfs_quota_us=10000 cpulimited
sudo cgexec -g cpu:cpulimited /usr/bin/ddcommand
```

## Caveat 2

For the settings `cpu.cfs_period_us` and `cpu.cfs_quota_us` to be available the Kernel needs to be compiled with config-flag `CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH`. Sadly the 3.16.x Kernel for **Debian Jessie** is not compiled with this flag by default, see this [feature request](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2015/10/msg00313.html).

This will be available in **Debian Stretch** though. One could also use the kernel from **jessie-backports**, which should have the flag enabled.

---

I hope this answer helps a few people with the same issue as me...

**PS:** An easy way to test wether CPUquota is working in your environment is:

```
$ apt-get install stress
$ systemd-run -p CPUQuota=25% --slice=stress -- stress -c <your cpu count>
```

and watch with `top` or `htop`, the load should be spread (evenly) accross all cpus/cores, summing up to 25%.

## Alternative

As an alternative tool one could use cpu-limit which should be available in most distros, eg.

```
$ apt-get install cpulimit
$ cpulimit -l 10 -P /usr/bin/ddcommand
```

It works by sending `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` to the attached command to pause and resume its operation.

AFAIK it was difficult to control multiple separate/stand-alone processes simultaneously with this, in like *group them together*, but there might also be solution for this...

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom, this was an old problem and I dealt with it by finally using CPUShares option, but your answer enlights many aspects of the problem and for that reason I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you for the CPUQuota test with systemd-run. That was just what i was looking for! However I think it should read `systemd-run -p CPUQuota=25% --slice stress 'stress --cpu <your cpu count>'`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar task to limit CPU usage, but the use case was completely different. It was to stress a regression test suite on local machine to simulate what it undergoes on a loaded CI server (what causes non-deterministic or flaky behaviour of tests). This worked like a charm, in contrary to `cpulimit` and `stress`.

```
systemd-run -p CPUQuota="25%" --scope --uid=$USER --gid=$USER -- pytest ...
```

`--scope` made it inherit current shell environment and the command output to stdout as usual. The only difference in output was *Running scope as unit run-uN.scope* as the first line.

It requires root privileges to run and I have the GUI prompt from `pkttyagent`. It may be cumbersome to enter the password each time, if you need to run the command several times in a row, for instance to tweak `CPUQuota`, so prefixing the above command with `sudo -E env PATH=$PATH` would simplify the task.

Just in case, because there are reports it didn't work/wasn't supported on older versions.

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-51-generic
$ systemd --version | head -n 1
systemd 229
```